# Expected Value dice rolling

Tags: expectation

You roll a die until you get the number five. What is the expected value of the maximum roll you see(don't include 5, we only consider rolls upto and before the 5). I created a solution to this problem, although I am still confused because of the dependency on the number of rolls. Any commentary would be appreciated

Suppose that it takes $n$ rolls to see a 5. Then 
$E(n) = \frac{1}{6}^n \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot n \cdot \frac{2}{6}^{n-1} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot n \cdot \frac{3}{6}^{n-1} \cdot 3 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot n \cdot \frac{4}{6}^{n-1} \cdot 4 + (1-\frac{5}{6}^n) \cdot 6$.
The probabilities in the expected value function are computed as the probability that number will be the highest out of n rolls. For instance for 2 being the highest roll, we have to have two appear in the sequence of $n$ rolls, and then have all the other rolls be two or less, which corresponds to probability $\frac{1}{6} \cdot n \cdot \frac{2}{6}^{n-1}$. Now my question is how this depends on the number of rolls. For the overall expected value do we simply use the expected number of flips to roll a five, which is six, and then plug 5 into the equation to get the overall expected value? (when I do I get 4.42)

(as another thought, should i integrate the expected value function from $n=0$ to $\infty$?)

Comment: Please define your X

Comment: Sorry, it should be n

Comment: You have confusion between minimum and maximum in your question. You start with the minimum but then talk about $2$ being the highest roll.  It can't be highest because you know you throw a $5$.

Comment: I am just considering rolls up until the point that a 5 is rolled. The 5 isn't part of the values considered. I'll edit the question

Comment: @GTOgod thanks.  So is that it (just finding the expected number of rolls until you hit a 5, or are you still working on the problem of the minimum? What do you have so far on that front?

Comment: I changed the problem to the maximum, because my work represented that, although minimum would not be too hard to come up with after solving this version. So thinking about it I think I have to associate the probability of that $n$ rolls occurs and multiply that by the $E(n)$ function and sum up all the (countably many) values from 0 to infinity. This makes me think that $E(5)$ is not a bad estimate, but it's probably not correct considering the distribution of the n rolls

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a five-sided die, with faces $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$.  You roll it $k$ times.  What is the expected value of the max roll? Well, it's going to depend on $k$.
\begin{equation}
P(max=1) = \frac{1}{5^k}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(max=2) = \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^k - \frac{1}{5^k}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(max=3) = \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k - \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^k
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(max=4) = \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k - \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(max=6) = 1 - \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E[max] = 6 - 2 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k - \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k - \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^k - \frac{1}{5^k}
\end{equation}
Basically, the probability that the $m$th highest value is the maximum is the probability that all the rolls were at most that large, *minus* the probability that all the rolls were smaller than that value.

Now, we want to sum over $k$, using the probability that the $k+1$st roll is a 5 and none of the others are.
\begin{equation}
E = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( 6 - 2 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k - \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k - \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^k - \frac{1}{5^k} \right) * \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^k \frac{1}{6}
= \frac{1}{6} * \left( 6 * 6 - 2 * 3 - 2 - \frac{3}{2} - \frac{6}{5} \right) = \frac{1}{6} * ( 25.3 ) \approx 4.2167
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't think the final expected value in the problem depends on $k$. Simply because we can correlate a probability for each $k$ meaning we can sum over all k to get the total EV

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of my derivation when I clicked submit -- I did finish it up shortly thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

There is an incompleteness in the statement of the problem.  Since the maximum is taken over the values seen only in throws prior to the appearance of the 5, **it needs to be specified what will be declared as the “maximum” if the very first throw is a 5** (which can happen with probability of 1/6 ). Happy to edit the answer once you provide that specification, which will be needed in the last step below.

Let t be the throw when you first hit a 5. Then $P(t=k)=\frac{1}{6}{(\frac{5}{6}})^{k-1}$.

Now, we can consider the maximum of the set of throws, $M$. Conditional on $t$ taking the value $k$, $M$ can take values 1,2,3,4 and 6 according to the following distribution function 
$$F(M=1|t=k)=(\frac{1}{5} )^{k-1}$$
$$F(M=2|t=k)=(\frac{2}{5} )^{k-1}$$
$$F(M=3|t=k)=(\frac{3}{5} )^{k-1}$$
$$F(M=4|t=k)=(\frac{4}{5} )^{k-1}$$
$$F(M=6|t=k)=(\frac{5}{5} )^{k-1}$$

By differencing these, we get  the conditional probability masses $P(M=m|t=k)$.  For example, 
$$P(M=6|t=k)=\frac{5^{k-1}-4^{k-1}}{5^{k-1}}$$

Now, we can compute the distribution of $M$ itself. 
$$P(M=m)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} P(M=m|t=k) P(t=k)$$ For example 
$$P(M=4)= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{4^{k-1}-3^{k-1}}{5^k} \frac{1}{6}{(\frac{5}{6}})^{k-1}= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{4^{k-1}-3^{k-1}}{6^k}$$

**Note that these probabilities sum only to 5/6 because 1/6 of the probability lies in the case $k=1$ where $M$ has not been defined.** (You could choose to define it any way. Zero would be a reasonable definition, if you are going to give away a prize equal to $M$ dollars when the game ends by 5 being hit. If 5 is hit on the first try, no payout is made).

Now, the expectation is simple to compute because each term is the sum of a geometric series.

$$E(M)= \sum_{m \in \{1,2,3,4,6\} } m P(M=m)$$

$$E(M)=1 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{6^k}+2 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k-1}-1^{k-1}}{6^k}+3
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{3^{k-1}-2^{k-1}}{6^k}+4 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{4^{k-1}-3^{k-1}}{6^k}+6 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{5^{k-1}-4^{k-1}}{6^k}$$
This comes out to be $$\frac{1}{6}[30 - 0.2 - 0.5 -1 - 4] = 4.05$$

This is also the final answer if you choose to define $M$ as 0 for the case $k=1$

**Note**: If, for some reason, you decide that in the case of hitting 5 on the first try, you want to declare $M$ to be 1 (can’t see a good reason to do that), then the computation of the expectation will have one additional term $1 \times \frac{1}{6}$, which makes the expectation equal to $4.216667$.

Answer (score -2):

Let $P_k$ be the probability that the first instnace to see a 5 was the kth roll, then $E=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kP_k\ where\ P_k=\frac{1}{6} (\frac{5}{6})^{k-1}$